# xcode swift: how to drag a button?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working with xcode to create a view that allows users to drag buttons. with the code below, I can move the button to the touch and drag from there, but I cant click the button and drag.

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    for obj in touches {
        let touch = obj as! UITouch
        let location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
        word1Button.center = location
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buttons respond to touch events, so when the user touches down within the bounds of a button the view underneath will not receive those touch events. You can get around this by using a gesture recogniser on your button instead of relying on the lower level touch delivery methods. A long press gesture recognizer would probably work best:

```
// Where you create your button:
let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleLongPress:")
word1Button.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)

//...

func handleLongPress(longPress: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    switch longPress.state {
    case .Changed:
        let point = longPress.locationInView(view)
        button.center = point
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Note that by default, the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` needs the user to hold down for 0.5 seconds before the gesture starts recognizing (and therefore starts dragging). You can change this with the `minimumPressDuration` property of `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`. Be careful not to make it too short though - as soon as the gesture recognizes it will cancel other touches to the button, preventing the button action from being fired when the touch is lifted.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! For now I ended up using an imageView with a label over the top. If I run into a lack of features later, I will try this out.